# How to use temporary Channel in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm new in Spring Integration, I'm trying to get the message from temporary channel.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-default-reply-channel) there is a temporary channel use by spring.
I guess it named `NullChannel`

I need my `gateway` returns the value from temporary channel.

`http controller -> gateway -> direct channel -> activator 1 -> queue channel -> activator 2`

So my `activator 2` will put the new value into temporary channel, so the `gateway` will retrieve the value from temporary channel

[image]

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class Activator2 {
    
@Autowired
private NullChannel nullChannel;

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "asyncChannel")
public void plus(Integer message){
    try {
        message++;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        nullChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
        log.info("Activator 2: " +message );

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("I don't want to sleep");
    }
    
}
}
```

it not working. I'm not sure if everything is well connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NullChannel` is like `/dev/null` in Unix; it just discards the value.

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "asyncChannel")
public Integer plus(Integer message){
    return message;
}
```

will automatically do what you want.

If there is no `outputChannel`, the framework sends the result to the `replyChannel` header.